# Can I trigger an AWS Lambda function from EBS written in Java? Can I pass parameter to it? What other services I need to use to use Lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Basically, I want to schedule a small event when some event happens in my web service written in Java and hosted on AWS ElasticBeanstalk. Also, I want to trigger that Lambda function on specific date and time and also if possible by passing few parameters.

Comment: This is tremendously broad. Try to narrow it down and show us the background research you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can invoke AWS Lambda functions from your AWS ElasticBeanstalk. In fact you can do this from any other Java program if you have aws_access_key_id and 
aws_secret_access_key

There are no other services that you will need to directly invoke lambda, but depending on other use cases Lambda seamlessly integrates with AWS SNS, AWS API Gateway, AWS S3 notifications to name a few

And you can pass the parameters as well in the input payload

For details about scheduling Lambda executions [click here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html)